# Actionbar Icons are not showing

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have searched around the forum, and I still do not know what's the problem. Action bar Icons dont show up. Actually, Im following a book.. 
and I did all what in the book is to let the icons appear.
I hope I get some answers. 
Thanks a lot.

```html
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.hfad.bitsandpizzas.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_create_order"
        android:title="@string/action_create_order"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_create_order"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

```js
package com.hfad.bitsandpizzas;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    // Implementing this method adds any items in the menu resource file to the action bar.
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

[image: Emulator]

Comment: `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"` decided that there was no room, so if you insist, change it to `always`.

Comment: I tried it .. still not working.

Comment: So the problem is that you want to show it on the action bar directly, instead of going to the overflow menu (those three dots) ?

Comment: @Yashasvi yess.. I want to show it directly. not in the overflow.

Comment: In my case, it's showing directly on action bar (testing on 5x emulator with api 23) . On which device are you testing?

Comment: @Yashasvi I have used Emulators with API 17, 21, 23.. none of them has shown the icon.. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK people, I have continued reading the book.. 
it is writing that : The action item may appear in the overflow instead. This is due to a bug in dome revisions of the v7 appcompact library. If this is a problem in your app, report it in Google.

Thanks a lot Guys.

Answer (score 1):

You can't show icons in overflow menu. By default all menu items displayed in overflow menu are displaying without icons, only text.

Comment: I don't want it do be displayed in the overflow menu.. i want to see it directly there in the actionbar..

Answer (score 1):

Change your menu to:

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_test"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
</menu>
```

orderInCategory should be equal to 100 to make its icon visible...

Comment: Thanks man, but it didn't help.. could be the problem from the style resource file ? 
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light"> </style>

</resources>

Comment: You must use the Theme.AppCompat as your base theme:

Android Toolbar extend ActionBarActivity theme